# Select rows from all tables containing specific column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have several tables with a column called `something`.

How can I select all the rows of column `something` from all the tables that have such a column?

Can it be done in one query?

Answer (score 3):

On approach is to create a dynamic a script:

```
SELECT 'SELECT something FROM ' || table_name ||';'
  FROM information_schema.columns
  WHERE column_name = 'something'
```

then run the output of the script generated. If you are concerned about schema names, column types, unions, etc modify the dynamic sql generation accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done with a SQL query using UNION operator.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/queries-union.html

```
SELECT something FROM table_a UNION 
SELECT something FROM table_b
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
begin;
do $$
declare
  stmt text;
  tbls text[];
  col text := 'x';
begin
  select
    array_agg(format(
      'select ''%2$s.%3$s'' as tbl, %1$I::text from %2$I.%3$I',
      col, table_schema, table_name))
    into tbls
    from information_schema.columns
    where column_name = col;
  raise info '%', tbls;
  stmt := array_to_string(tbls, ' union all ');
  raise info '%', stmt;
  execute 'declare foo cursor for ' || stmt;
end $$;
fetch all from foo;
rollback;
```

and result is (for the my test DB):

```
INFO:  {"select 'public.dummy' as tbl, x::text from public.dummy","select 'nd.t' as tbl, x::text from nd.t"}
INFO:  select 'public.dummy' as tbl, x::text from public.dummy union all select 'nd.t' as tbl, x::text from nd.t
╔══════════════╤═══╗
║     tbl      │ x ║
╠══════════════╪═══╣
║ public.dummy │ X ║
║ nd.t         │ 3 ║
╚══════════════╧═══╝
(2 rows)
```

It should be executed in the single transaction (`begin; ... rollback;`) because the cursor created by `declare ...` statement exists only in the transaction.